# How to add a business logic layer to the program?

Tags: java-8

I created a program that generates numbers more and less than the number that we enter in the text line. Tell me how you can add a business logic layer to this program.

main.java

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String[]argc){
    GraphicalUserInterface gui = new GraphicalUserInterface();
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setResizable(false);
 }
}
```

GraphicalUserInterface.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
public class GraphicalUserInterface extends JFrame {

int anInt;
private JButton buttonMore = new JButton("Генерировать больше");
private JButton buttonLess = new JButton("Генерировать меньше");

private JTextField textField = new JTextField("", 5);
private JLabel labelOne = new JLabel("254");
private JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel("125");
private JLabel labelZero = new JLabel("");

public GraphicalUserInterface() {

    super("Lab1_GUI");
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 150);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 10, 10, 10));

    container.add(textField);
    container.add(labelZero);

    buttonMore.addActionListener(event -> {
        anInt = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

labelOne.setText(String.valueOf
 (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(anInt, 1000)));
    });

    container.add(buttonMore);
    container.add(labelOne);

    buttonLess.addActionListener(event -> {
        anInt = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
        labelTwo.setText(String.valueOf
          (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(anInt)));
    });
    container.add(buttonLess);
    container.add(labelTwo);
}
}
```

[image: sequence diagram]

it is not clear how to add business logic to it

Comment: What do you think, is “business logic”?

Comment: two methods of generation (over / under) are my business logic

Comment: The phrase “business logic” has no meaning on its own. Just try to say what you want to achieve without using the term “business logic” and consider that the average reader of this site does not understand Russian. Generally, for any nontrivial project, starting with a user interface, to be filled with actual program logic afterwards, is the wrong order.